# Changing the index in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

I have string in my data that looks like this in my output:

```
string_sequence = 'MLSPDLPDSAWNTRLLCRVMLCLLGAGSVAAGVIQSPRHLIKEKRETATLKCYPIPRHDTVYWYQQGPGQDPQFLISFYEKMQSDKGSIPDRFSAQQFSDYHSELNMSSLELGDSALYFCASSL'
```

In the next step I had to digest this aminoacid-sequence with the typsin-enzym, which splits the sequence from the string K and R, but if there is a P it doesnt.
The output are the peptides which I need and is saved in the datatype of a list and looks like the following:

```
list_sequence =    ['MLSPDLPDSAWNTR', 'LLCR', 'VMLCLLGAGSVAAGVIQSPR', 'HLIK', 'EK', 'R', 'ETATLK', 'CYPIPR', 'HDTVYWYQQGPGQDPQFLISFYEK', 'MQSDK', 'GSIPDR', 'FSAQQFSDYHSELNMSSLELGDSALYFCASSL']
```

now I have a problem with my indexes, which I can find in my database.
In the aminoacid-sequence is in the 18th position a `V`.
I have to find now in the exact same position in my list-datatype the `V`.
I could find this by counting the aminoacids by hand, but in a sequencelength of 1000 aminocids it could be a problem.

My thought is now like this:
I know that the index of each `list_sequence[i]` starts with a 0.

Is there any way, where I can say in my code that the index in the `list_sequence[1]` starts with the `len(list_sequence[0])` and the index of `list_sequence[2]` starts with 18. So the next number after the last postion of the list_sequence-index.

Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by " the index of list_sequence[2] starts with 18"? An index is a number, it cannot start with a number. Do you want ``list_sequence[2]`` to return ``V`` or ``VMLCLLGAGSVAAGVIQSPR ``? Or do you just want a *separate* map from the indices of ``list_sequence`` to ``string_sequence``?

Comment: there is a string in all of the list_sequence-indices. These indices always start with a zero. My question or goal is to cheange the startnumber of these indices.
Do you know any fuction in python to do this?

Comment: So you want ``list_sequence[2][18]`` to return ``V``? And ``list_sequence[2][17]`` to be an ``IndexError``?

Comment: the first case in the list_sequence looses the 18 because i convertet the string to a list. With that the positions get lost because of the overwriting the beginning of all list_sequence[i] to a zero

Comment: I understand what information you have lost. I understand that you want to preserve it, but not the format you need instead.

Comment: i still want the list but want to formate the indices.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Maybe the most readable way to do something as you want is to store the size of each sequence linked to the sequence itself or also a cumulative size incrementation.

```py
list_sequence =    ['MLSPDLPDSAWNTR', 'LLCR', 'VMLCLLGAGSVAAGVIQSPR', 'HLIK', 'EK', 'R', 'ETATLK', 'CYPIPR', 'HDTVYWYQQGPGQDPQFLISFYEK', 'MQSDK', 'GSIPDR', 'FSAQQFSDYHSELNMSSLELGDSALYFCASSL']

cumulative = 0
for idx, item in enumerate(list_sequence):
  len_item = len(item)
  list_sequence[idx] = (item, len_item, cumulative)
  cumulative += len_item

print(list_sequence)
```

Output (first element of each list is your sub_sequence, second is its length, third is the starting idx of the subsequence in your initial full sequence)

```
[('MLSPDLPDSAWNTR', 14, 0), ('LLCR', 4, 14), ('VMLCLLGAGSVAAGVIQSPR', 20, 18), ('HLIK', 4, 38), ('EK', 2, 42), ('R', 1, 44), ('ETATLK', 6, 45), ('CYPIPR', 6, 51), ('HDTVYWYQQGPGQDPQFLISFYEK', 24, 57), ('MQSDK', 5, 81), ('GSIPDR', 6, 86), ('FSAQQFSDYHSELNMSSLELGDSALYFCASSL', 32,92)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this by creating a class that does the mapping of indexes for you:

```
class sequence:
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.amino_seq=seq
        self.__split__sequence__()

    def __split__sequence__(self):
        #self.peptides =list()
        self.peptides_offset = list()
        count = 0
        for i in range(0, len(self.amino_seq)):
            if self.amino_seq[i]=='K' or self.amino_seq[i]=='R':
                #self.peptides.append(self.amino_seq[count:i+1])
                self.peptides_offset.append(count)
                count = i+1
        #self.peptides.append(self.amino_seq[count:len(self.amino_seq)])
        self.peptides_offset.append(len(self.amino_seq))

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.amino_seq[i]

    def peptide(self, i):
        return self.amino_seq[self.peptides_offset[i]:self.peptides_offset[ i + 1]]

    def peptide_amino(self, tup):
        if tup[1]<0:
            return self.amino_seq[self.peptides_offset[tup[0]]]
        else:
            return self.amino_seq[self.peptides_offset[tup[0]] + tup[1]]

    def peptide_offset(self, tup):
        if tup[1]<0:
            return self.peptides_offset[tup[0]]
        else:
            return self.peptides_offset[tup[0]] + tup[1]

    def get_peptide_tuple(self, i):
        count=0
        for j in self.peptides_offset:
            if j>=i:
                return (count, i-j)
            count = count+1
        return (-1,-1)

    def get_number_of_peptides(self):
        return len(self.peptides_offset)-1
```

You can then use it like this:

```
for i in range(0,seq.get_number_of_peptides()):
    print seq.peptide(i)

print seq[18]
print seq.peptide_amino((2,0))
print seq.peptide_offset((2,0))
print seq[seq.peptide_offset((2,0))]
print seq.get_peptide_tuple(18)
print seq[seq.peptide_offset(seq.get_peptide_tuple(18))]
```

which outputs

> MLSPDLPDSAWNTR
>   LLCR
>   VMLCLLGAGSVAAGVIQSPR
>   HLIK
>   EK
>   R
>   ETATLK
>   CYPIPR
>   HDTVYWYQQGPGQDPQFLISFYEK
>   MQSDK
>   GSIPDRFSAQQFSDYHSELNMSSLELGDSALYFCASSL
>   V
>   V
>   18
>   V
>   (2, 0)
>   V

The upside also is that the `class` also only stores the sequence and the offset mapping but never the split sequence of peptides.